# Processing audio of url stream in unspecified format

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, vlc, audio-streaming

I'm trying to process url audio streams from list of urls. Each url can have different format and I'm trying to find a library that can handle all the format kinds and give me the raw stream data that I can then process.

I have a code that can process wav stream. the problem is that some urls are in aac or mp3 formats and I need to handle each one of them correctly.

This is the code to process wav stream:

```py
from urllib2 import urlopen
#to python3.x
#from urllib.request import urlopen
import pyaudio

pyaud = pyaudio.PyAudio()

srate=44100

stream = pyaud.open(format = pyaud.get_format_from_width(1),
                channels = 1,
                rate = srate,
                output = True)

url = "http://myurl/hara.wav"
u = urlopen(url)

data = u.read(8192)

while data:

    stream.write(data)
    data = u.read(8192)
```

This code currently fails when the format is not wav. I tried reading about ffmpeg or vlc to format the urls but I haven't found a working way.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: sometimes server sends file's type in response's header

Comment: FFmpeg is probably what you want.  Just use STDIO.  `ffmpeg -i <url> -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -`  That outputs raw PCM data to your app.

Comment: is there a way i can integrate this command with my current python code? @Brad

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't tell you how.  I don't code in Python.  Just figure out how to execute FFmpeg as a child process and get its STDOUT to your Python, and you're good to go.